# Handle Browser beforeunload with react-router-dom v6 page navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a simple application with the navigation built with `react-router` v6. My use case is to call an API with the last updated state on page unload.

```js
const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
  console.log("Running unload");
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);
}, []);
```

With the above code when I reload the browser the handler is getting called. But when I'm trying to navigate via sidebar having `NavLink`, the unload is not getting called because `react-router-dom` do client side routing so page is not actually never getting unload. So How can I run the piece of code on page unload with `react-router-dom` Navigation?

Sample Code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-pond-gt5u6d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to handle all the different ways a user leaves the component differently. Use `beforeunload` when the page is reloaded or closed, use an effect cleanup function to handle when the component is just unmounted.

Example:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = () => {
    console.log("Running unload");
  };

  // handles when page is unloaded
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

  // cleanup function handles when component unmounts
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handleBeforeUnload);

    handleBeforeUnload();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew Reese. Actually I tried that but Clean up function is not always accessing current state. Consider I have multiple state and on leave I want to store that state. Now to get the current state every time I have to add dependencies in useEffect and If I add that cleanup will run multiple time. If I keep dependencies empty array to make sure cleanup run only one time, I'm not able to access the current state.

Comment: @UtsavPatel Hmmm, I just knew that would come up. I didn't include it initially as to give you the benefit of a doubt that you had it handled already. Cache the state in a React ref that is accessed in the cleanup function. Would you like me to update my answer with an example?

Comment: Ya I think I figured that as well. But I'm just concern, Is that a right way to do or is there any other way? I'm keeping the state and keeping ref to watch over the change of state. If I have multiple state and it can go big enough will that cause any issue?

Comment: @UtsavPatel It's my humble opinion caching a reference to a state object in a React ref is a perfectly valid use case in this scenario. The alternative is as you say, to add the state as a dependency so the cleanup function can re-close over the current/latest state value, but then the cleanup function runs ***way*** more often than just when the component unmounts.