# React browser "back" press handle/listener

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, dom-events, event-listener

I have an Issue with my react project...

I am trying to trigger "triggerDisband" function whenever the window closes.

So far the 'beforeunload' listener did the job well, it works on browser refresh, URL change or simply closing the window, which is exactly what I want, except I also want it to trigger on "back" browser press, but for some reason it doesn't... GPT has no idea why my current code isn't working and he didn't give a working solution.

Anyone knows what I should add here?

```
    // onMount
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!SocketManager.instance.roomId) {
            navigate('/')
        }

        EventsManager.instance.on(
            SocketEvents.SEQUENCE_GENERATED,
            'GameManager',
            handleSequenceGen
        )

        EventsManager.instance.on(
            SocketEvents.GAME_RESTARTED,
            'GameManager',
            handleTryAgain
        )

        EventsManager.instance.on(
            SocketEvents.DISBAND_GAME,
            'GameManager',
            handleDisbandGame
        )


        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', triggerDisband)

        setTimeout(() => {
            sequenceIndexRef.current = 0
            if (SocketManager.instance.isHost) {
                EventsManager.instance.trigger(
                    SocketEvents.GENERATE_SEQUENCE,
                    {}
                )
            }
        }, 1000)
    }, [])

    // onBeforeDestroy
    useEffect(
        () => () => {
            EventsManager.instance.off(
                SocketEvents.BUTTON_CLICKED,
                'GameManager'
            )

            EventsManager.instance.off(
                SocketEvents.SEQUENCE_GENERATED,
                'GameManager'
            )

            EventsManager.instance.off(
                SocketEvents.GAME_RESTARTED,
                'GameManager'
            )

            EventsManager.instance.off(SocketEvents.DISBAND_GAME, 'GameManager')

            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', triggerDisband)
        },
        []
    )

    const triggerDisband = () => {
        EventsManager.instance.trigger(SocketEvents.ON_GAME_LEAVE, {})
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Tried using popstate window event but for some reason that didn't work, maybe its something to do with react-router-dom that im not understanding

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75550412/handle-browser-beforeunload-with-react-router-dom-v6-page-navigation/75550447#75550447

Comment: Wow! thanks, it worked! very much appreciated. you can post this as the answer and i'll accept it.